# Angular core/feature/shared modules: what goes where

Tags: angular

First of all, it's not a duplicate of any other question and I've read the angular guide on that. However I still have several questions.

The feature module is the easiest one - you have a feature - group it into feature module. Let's say that in addition to obvious feature I have the pages which every application has:

1. Main Landing page (not app.template.html but something which it renders first in its router-outlet)
2. Error pages, like 404
3. Contacts page, about us page

I could probably move everything to feature module called 'static' but I don't like the name and also don't like grouping mostly unrelated things into the same module, i.e. error page and contact page. So, what is a pattern for mentioned pages?

Now, shared vs core module.
I have the following items:

1. CsrfService (sounds like core one to me)
2. Logger (angular2-logger service)
3. HttpModule(core or shared?)
4. Logged-in-guard and AuthService (I have NavbarComponent/NavbarModule and LoginComponent using the AuthService), so are those a feature (login/auth) or are those a core/shared?

So, the main question is how to choose decide for the items I listed and for new items like those.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

The answers to your question are subjective, however there are some recommendations from official docs you can follow: [What kinds of modules should I have and how should I use them?](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-kinds-of-modules-should-i-have-and-how-should-i-use-them). If you haven't read docs on `NgModule` and FAQ, I'd suggest spending a few hours studying them, things will be much clearer (at least they were for me :)

I'm using the following setup and it works quite well ***for me***:

- app/**shared** - This is the module where I keep small stuff that every other module will need. I have 3 submodules there `directives`, `components` and `pipes`, just to keep things organized a little better. Examples: `filesize.pipe`, `click-outside.directive`, `offline-status.component`...
- app/**public** - In this module I keep public routes and top-level components. Examples: `about.component`, `contact.component`, `app-toolbar.component`
- app/**core** - Services that app needs (and cannot work without) go here. Examples: `ui.service`, `auth.service`, `auth.guard`, `data.service`, `workers.service`....
- app/**protected** - Similar to **public**, only for authorized users. This module has protected routes and top-level components. Examples: `user-profile.component`, `dashboard.component`, `dashboard-sidebar.component`...
- app/**features** - This is the module where app functionalities are. They are organized in several submodules. If you app plays music, this is where `player`, `playlist`, `favorites` submodules would go. If you look at the [`@angular/material2`](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/lib) this would be an equivalent to their `MaterialModule` and many submodules, like `MdIconModule`, `MdSidenavModule` etc.
- app/**dev** - I use this module when developing, don't ship it in production.

General advice would be:

- organize features by functionality, not by pages
- keep similar routes in their own module (good for lazy loading)
- services that app needs to function go to **core**
- things you import more than once (or twice) are probably good for **shared**
- read docs in detail, lots of good stuff there

To answer your specific questions: I would put all those routes in one module - `static`, `public`, whatever the name. `CsrfService` - core, `Logger` - core or dev, `HttpModule` - core, you only need one instance (probably), `auth` - core. Don't put services in shared.

If you can't decide how/what to group in a feature, make a new app, copy specific feature folder and it should work there as well. If it doesn't, you'll need to organize things better.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I haven't seen it, only the angular styles guideline which has some advises on modules. Will read carefully.
Several things I still struggle with: navbar module (is it a feature or core?), LoginComponent aka LoginForm (I placed in the public), PageNotFound(I placed in public module, but it's catch-all route, so I have to reimport in app-routing.module, is it ok?). Will appreciate if you add it to your answer, in the meantime marking it as accepted. You helped me a lot.

Comment: I would put everything in public. For routing, recommendation is bit specific - you declare components in parent module, and just import them in routing module for use in routes. `PageNotFound` is a bit specific, it's not a big deal tho' where you put it, it's just one component (; My appr-routing.module only has one route - Public Module, where everything else is declared, but that's just me...

Comment: @VadimKirilchuk, navbar goes in shared.  It's not a core module.  If you have a lazy-loaded module for a route( ex: /login ),  it may also need the navbar module, and hence it needs to import it, so it imports the shared module.  If this lazy loaded module imported the core module, that would violate the principle of a core module being only loaded one time in the entire app.

Comment: @AugieGardner Thatnks for the tip. How should I subscribe to "the user logged in" event in navbar then? I.e. navbar should show the user picture when user has signed in and there is a separate LogInService which can be subscribed.. Are you saying that LogIn/AuthService is in core and navBar from shared will import the AuthService from core to subscribe? What if navbar view depends on the Service not in core, for instance in feature?

Comment: @VadimKirilchuk this is a good question.  The Auth service should be in Core.  The Core providers are inheritted by all lazy modules.  The Navbar component should import the Auth service.  Within the navbar, a simple `*ngIf="authService.isLoggedIn"` will bind correctly to the isLoggedIn boolean from Core, and can properly show your user picture thumbnail.  It needs not be an observable, per-se, though it can be.  
If Navbar depends on a service not in Core, it can import that as well.   If the Navbar itself has a separate Navbar service, I may make it a Feature module.

Comment: @AugieGardner If you are saying 'Navbar' as a common visual component, it should be in shared module, of course. But, if the 'Navbar' is global navigation bar, it can be included in core module because a global navigation bar is not imported more than once.

Comment: Where would you put a menu for example?